# Asynchronously running perl's backticks

Tags: perl, asynchronous, backticks

Right now I have a perl script that at a certain point, gathers and then processes the output of several bash commands, right now here is how I've done it:

```
if ($condition) {
  @output = `$bashcommand`;
  @output1 = `$bashcommand1`;
  @output2 = `$bashcommand2`;
  @output3 = `$bashcommand3`;
}
```

The problem is, each of these commands take a fairly amount of time, therefore, I'd like to know  if I could run them all at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a good use case for [`Forks::Super::bg_qx`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper#bg_qx).

```
use Forks::Super 'bg_qx';
$output = bg_qx $bashcommand;
$output1 = bg_qx $bashcommand1;
$output2 = bg_qx $bashcommand2;
$output3 = bg_qx $bashcommand3;
```

will run these four commands in the background. The variables used for return values (`$output`, `$output1`, etc.) are overloaded objects. Your program will retrieve the output from these commands (waiting for the commands to complete, if necessary) the next time those variables are referenced in the program.

```
... more stuff happens ...
# if $bashcommand is done, this next line will execute right away
# otherwise, it will wait until $bashcommand finishes ...
print "Output of first command was ", $output;

&do_something_with_command_output( $output1 );
@output2 = split /\n/, $output2;
...
```

**Update 2012-03-01:** v0.60 of Forks::Super [has some new constructions](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper#Forks%3a%3aSuper%3a%3abg_eval_tied_class) that let you retrieve results in list context:

```
if ($condition) {
    tie @output, 'Forks::Super::bg_qx', $bashcommand;
    tie @output1, 'Forks::Super::bg_qx', $bashcommand1;
    tie @output2, 'Forks::Super::bg_qx', $bashcommand2;
    tie @output3, 'Forks::Super::bg_qx', $bashcommand3;
}
...
```

Comment: @ikegami - It's undocumented, but if you need to know, you can poll `$output->is_ready` or inspect `$output->{job}` (which is a `Forks::Super::Job` object)

Comment: about order or completion, one can always use 'depend_on' feature of Forks::Super

Comment: @mob, actually its documents: "..Attempts to spawn a new process. On success, it returns a Forks::Super::Job object with information about the..."

Comment: @soulSurfer2010 - `depend_on` is about waiting for some jobs to complete before another job can start -- probably not helpful here

Comment: @soulSurfer2010 - "On success, it returns a Forks::Super::Job object ..." is from the documentation of `Forks::Super::fork`, not `Forks::Super::bg_qx`.

Answer (score 4):

On a Unix system, you should be able to open multiple command pipes, then run a loop calling `IO::Select` to wait for any of them to be ready to read; keep reading and slurping their output (with `sysread`) until they all reach end of file.

Unfortunately, apparently Win32 emulation of Unix `select` can't handle file I/O, so to pull it off on Windows you'll also have to add a layer of socket I/O, for which `select` works, see [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=494398).

Answer (score 2):

You can, but not using backticks.

Instead you'll need to open real file handles for them using `open(handle, "$bashcommand|");` and then do a proper `select` call to determine which one has new output that is ready for you.  It will take a lot more than the 6 lines you have above, but you will be able to run them all at the same time.

There are some classes in [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) that likely already manage some of the complexity for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to [Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-start-a-process-in-the-background).

[Proc::Background](http://search.cpan.org/~bzajac/Proc-Background-1.10/lib/Proc/Background.pm) looks promising.